# Drawing a curve in java Graphics2D

Tags: java, drawing, graphics2d, curve

How can I **draw a curve** using **java graphics2D**?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to draw curves, then use either [`Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) class ([`Path2D.Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html) or [`Path2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html)) which provide the methods `.moveTo(x, y)`, `.lineTo(x, y)`, `.curveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, endx, endy)`, and `.quadTo(cpx, cpy, endx, endy)`.

If you want to really dig into how curves work, then check this wonderful tutorial http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a curve like around a circle, use the `drawArc()` method found in the `Graphics` class. Here's the API page for it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29.

For cubic and quadratic curves, use the `java.awt.geom` package. Here's the Oracle page telling you how to use it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html.